# Custom error pages are not working IIS 7.0- It's display the default error page

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

We are having our site hosted on IIS 7.0 and Integrated mode and we have already set the custom error page like following.

```
  <customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.htm" mode="On">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error.htm"/>
   </customErrors>
```

It is redirecting url from the error page like following but its not displaying the url http://www.example.com/Error.htm?aspxerrorpath=/and its showing following error:

> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error
>   occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this
>   application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed
>   remotely (for security reasons). It
>   could, however, be viewed by browsers
>   running on the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this
>   specific error message to be viewable
>   on remote machines, please create a
>    tag within a
>   "web.config" configuration file
>   located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This
>    tag should then have
>   its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> ```
>       <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>      <configuration>
>      <system.web>
>        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
>      </system.web>
>     </configuration>
> ```
>
> Notes: The current error page you are
>   seeing can be replaced by a custom
>   error page by modifying the
>   "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's 
>   configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.
>
> ```
>            <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
>            <configuration>
>            <system.web>
>               <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
> ```
>
> defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>

Comment: What is the error you're getting (you should see it in the Application event log)?  If the error is related to the web.config file or if it's happening early on in the web site initialization, it could possibly not yet recognize the custom error page config settings.  Posting the exception details may help us figure out if this is the case.

Comment: Its simple if you put wrong connection string then it should show the error page but its showing page that have written as above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to use the [<httpErrors>](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors) element under *<system.webServer>* which is meant for IIS 7 etc.

Strange that it's different from the development version of IIS.  Perhaps if you use IIS Express for development it should match the IIS 7 behaviour more closely.

Answer (score 1):

You do have `mode="Off"` in your provided XML fragment.  Does changing it to `mode="On"` work?

Answer (score 1):

There is a selected solution already. I just want to contribute a bit more.

Another thing to look at is your **machine.Config** files, found in **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework{version}\Config** and
**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64{version}\Config**

Make sure you have.

```
<deployment retail="false"/>
```